# Make an application that can't be ended

Tags: android, tablet, android-homebutton, kiosk-mode

For my society, I'm to create an application that will be on a tablet in a public place. We don't want the tablet to be used for anything else but for our application. So, how is it possible to "avoid" the home button, task list, etc? I would like to see only my application on the tablet (no task bar, system buttons, etc).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does. What you need is put the tablet in `kiosk mode`. [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html) is a way to achieve this. If you do not want to go through thridy part software you should compile your own android version customizing few things like  the launcher/settings.

Comment: Any chance to know how sureLock hides Home button?